# Make nautilus not show desktop via SSH

Tags: ssh, gnome, xorg, nautilus

Most of the days I am connected to my home server (running Debian) via a ssh shell from my laptop. Most of the tasks are done in the prompt, but sometimes I like to have drag-and-drop-file managers, like GNOME's default nautilus. (I of course mean that i use ssh -X user@server)

However, nautilus draws "it's" desktop over my local desktop. It draws the files placed there and the default Debian wallpaper. Is there a way to run or configure nautilus to not draw theese things at all, or should I use another graphical file manager when doing things remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag and drop like this is not trivial to implement over network, and running a file manager over X forwarding like this will not (trivially) work for the purpose.

You should use [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) instead to mount your remote server in your local file system over SSH, and the use a *local* file manager to browse that mount. This way drag and drop will work over SSH, and the file manager will be much snappier.

Another alternative is to use a graphical [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) client such as [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/), which will allow you to log in over SSH and get a tree view of your remote files, with drag and drop support.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! Of course, using SFTP is easier, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

After SSH, run nautilus as follows:

```
nautilus --no-desktop
```

...which tells nautilus not to manage the desktop, as per the nautilus man page. Works fine for me after that.

```
man nautilus
```